# How to identify the Duplicates of one value with different values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a Macro to Identify duplicate of one value with different values in excel .

if you see the image below there are 2 cluster which have different state & Cities highlighted in yellow colour. i want these cluster # should come in Sheet2 in A Column.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, y As Long, w As Long, LastRow As Long, LastRow2 As Long
    Dim Cluster1 As String, Cluster2 As String, FullDesc1 As String, FullDesc2 As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Diff As Boolean

    'Change sheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

        For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1

            If .Range("A" & i).Value <> "" Then

                Cluster1 = .Range("A" & i).Value

                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, Cluster1) > 1 Then

                    FullDesc1 = Cluster1 & "_" & .Range("B" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & i).Value

                    Diff = False

                    For y = LastRow To 2 Step -1

                        If y < i Then

                            Cluster2 = .Range("A" & y).Value
                            FullDesc2 = Cluster2 & "_" & .Range("B" & y).Value & "_" & .Range("C" & y).Value

                            If (Cluster1 = Cluster2) And (FullDesc1 <> FullDesc2) Then
                                Diff = True
                                Exit For
                            Else
                                Diff = False
                            End If

                        End If

                    Next y

                     If Diff = True Then

                        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

                        For w = LastRow To 2 Step -1

                            If .Range("A" & w).Value = Cluster1 Then

                                LastRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                                .Range("A" & w & ":C" & w).Cut ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & LastRow2 + 1)
                                .Rows(w).EntireRow.Delete

                            End If

                        Next w

                    End If

                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```